# All exe's crash on Windows XP SP3 after clean install Mono 2.10.9

Tags: mono

I am a Mono noob, so bear with me...

I just installed Mono 2.10.9 and opened the Samples folder - any .exe I've tried crashed.
Am I doing something wrong here...?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so Mono executables can NOT be started in windows directly. You have to let the mono.exe take care of that.

So start a command line and use "Mono SomeProgram.exe" to start a mono application...